# What specifically is being searched in Thunderbird Quick Search?

Tags: email, thunderbird, search

Thunderbird offers a "quick search" bar across the top of the screen, and when used, the results appear as below.

What, explicitly, is being searched in this quick search?

- Body of message?
- Headers of message? If so, which ones.
- Flags? If so, which ones.
- Folder the message is in?

The problem I need to solve is that I need to add a reference number to emails (example below: 12345678), but this reference number needs to be attached to the message in a place which can be searched using quick search.

The broad goal is ease of use - "oh you can just" solutions to the problem won't work.

[image: Screenshot of thunderbird search results]

Answer (score 0):

The *Quick Filter* apparently only looks at the *Subject*, *From* and *To* (*Correspondents*) fields by *default*. However, one can *choose* to select on the basis of *Tag*.

The easiest way to add a reference number to a Thunderbird Message is to right-click on the message and add a *Tag*. The tag can be a number, as in your example, or any alphanumeric sequence. It can be added at that time *de novo*, or chosen from a list.

To use *Quick Filter* to find that tag,

- Click on the button to the right of the filter box to show the *Quick Filter Menu*.
- Select *Tags*.
- In the box on the left, choose which tags to select or to exclude.

[image: Quick Filter on Tag]

Note that your screenshot looks different from that above, taken from Thunderbird 115.7, the latest as this is being written. You might need to access that menu differently, or to update to the latest version.

**Update:**
*Tag* selection in v. 115.8.0 of Thunderbird is now *via* a separate button.

[image: Thunderbird 115.8.0 Quick Filter screenshot]